# Can I get my instance of mechanize.Browser to stay on the same page after calling b.form.submit()?

Tags: python, screen-scraping, mechanize

In Python's mechanize.Browser module, when you submit a form the browser instance goes to that page. For this one request, I don't want that; I want it just to stay on the page it's currently on and give me the response in another object (for looping purposes). Anyone know a quick to do this?

EDIT:
Hmm, so I have this kind of working with ClientForm.HTMLForm.click(), which returns a urllib2 request, but I need the cookies from mechanize's cookiejar to be used on my urllib2.urlopen request. Is there a method in mechanize that will let me send a request just like urllib2 with the exception that cookies will be imported?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to my immediate question in the headline is yes, with `mechanize.Browser.open_novisit()`. It works just like `open()`, but it doesn't change the state of the Browser instance -- that is, it will retrieve the page, and your Browser object will stay where it was.